# parameter_overrides showing up in AWS SAM deploy output, but the parameter values are not being overriden

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, deployment, parameters, aws-sam

I have an AWS SAM application with two functions. One function has two variables: AlpacaAPIKey and AlpacaSecretKey. The YAML template looks like this (note - just included relevant part):

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  Symbol Management Stack

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 360
    MemorySize: 512

Parameters:
  AlpacaAPIKey:
    Type: String
    Default: Key
  AlpacaSecretKey:
    Type: String
    Default: Secret

Resources:
    SymbolManagementFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            CodeUri: SymbolManagement/
            Handler: maintain_symbols.lambda_handler
            Runtime: python3.7
            FunctionName: StockSymbolManagementFunction
            Environment:
            Variables:
                AlpacaAPIKey: Key
                AlpacaSecretKey: Secret
```

There is a separate **env.json** file which stores the values of the variables to use during local testing. This is fine.

For deploying, I have the **parameter_overrides** defined in **samconfig.toml**:

```
parameter_overrides = [
    "AlpacaAPIKey=value1",
    "AlpacaSecretKey=value2"
]
```

Clearly the above values are fake. Anyway, the following output is generated using **sam deploy**:

```
Deploying with following values  
Stack name : MyStack
Region     : us-east-1  
Confirm changeset : True  
Disable rollback  : False  
Deployment s3 bucket : aws-sam-cli-managed-default-samclisourcebucket-fakename  
Capabilities : ["CAPABILITY_IAM", "CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND"]  
Parameter overrides : {"AlpacaAPIKey": "value1", "AlpacaSecretKey": "value2"}  
Signing Profiles : {}
```

Examining the environment variables on the console after deployment, they haven't changed:

[image]

Any insight as to why the parameters are not being updated would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Jonathan

---

**Update 28th June 2023**

As I resolved this issue, I realized that an important piece of information was omitted in the description. The application has two nested applications.  The application in the description is actually a nested application. The **--parameter-overrides** for **sam deploy** (or **parameter_overrides**  in **samconfig.toml**) overrides parameters at the parent level by default. However, in the parent **template.yaml**, I hadn't defined any parameters. Will provide a code sample of the solution in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the description update, this application is actually an application with two nested applications. I had configured parameters in the child YAML template, but **sam deploy** applies **--parameter-overrides** to the root YAML template by default.

To solve the matter, I created parameters in the parent YAML template, and passed them through to the child templates. sam deploy with **--parameter-overrides** now works as expected.

**Root YAML Template:**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
 Parent Trading Stack

Parameters:
  AlpacaAPIKey:
     Type: String
     Default: Key
  AlpacaSecretKey:
     Type: String
     Default: Secret

Resources:
  SymbolManagement:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
    Properties:
      Location: symbol-management.yaml
      Parameters:
        AlpacaAPIKey: !Ref AlpacaAPIKey
        AlpacaSecretKey: !Ref AlpacaSecretKey
```

**Child YAML Template:**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  Symbol Management Stack

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 360
    MemorySize: 512

Parameters:
  AlpacaAPIKey:
    Type: String
    Default: Key
  AlpacaSecretKey:
    Type: String
    Default: Secret

Resources:
  SymbolManagementFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: SymbolManagement/
      Handler: maintain_symbols.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      FunctionName: StockSymbolManagementFunction
      Environment:
        Variables:
          AlpacaAPIKey: !Ref AlpacaAPIKey
          AlpacaSecretKey: !Ref AlpacaSecretKey
```

Result as expected after **sam deploy**:

[image]

The flow of the parameters from a **--parameter-overrides** standpoint is:

**--parameter-overrides** -> Parameters defined in root template -> Parameters defined in child template -> Usage in environment variables.

In order for this to work, the **!Ref** keyword needs to be used throughout for the parent to be picked up at each step.

Curious to know if there are alternatives to this method for nested applications as I'm not a seasoned developer.